# Phpmyadmin connect with c# code

Tags: c#, mysql

I have phpmyadmin and mysql workbench, so if I write data of my table in mysql workbench in the code work gook! But if I write data of my table in php image description here
[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U75Qu.png)

Comment: Check your connection string details. like a userid,password and server name.

Comment: is same that mysql workbench

Comment: @MikeMigor, it would seem as though you have your password wrong or that you have incorrectly setup authentication for connecting with `root`. As an aside to this take a look here: [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx). At the moment your code is open to SQL injection attacks.